# identifying the beacon in the method didEnterRegion(Region region) and didExitRegion(Region region)

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon

want to do this:

```
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    if(region.getId1.equals("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")){
     //display message: welcome to area 1
    } else if(region.getId1.equals("yyyyyyyyy")){
     //display message: welcome to area 2
    }  
}
```

the problem is that when calling get.Id1 the value returns null and not have to differentiate beacons

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use the ranging APIs in order to get the specific identifiers of the visible beacons.  You can start ranging inside the `didEnterRegion` callback, and you will get a callback in a different method with the identifiers.  Like this:

```
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
       beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
       beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
}

public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
            if(beacon.getId1().toString().equals("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")){
                //display message: welcome to area 1
            } else if(region.getId1().toString().equals("yyyyyyyyy")){
                //display message: welcome to area 2
         }   
}
```